# Making a USB connection over WIFI

Tags: usb, wireless, automotive

I have been using wired Carplay/Android Auto in my car. I checked a few existing wireless auto solutions and realised the present solution has a complete system inside to handle the connection.

This made me wonder if we can make a device like

`Mobile`[Bluetooth/Wifi] > `Hardware`[Bluetooth/Wifi Receiver > Convert to USB protocol > USB Male connector] > `Car`[Wired connection].

The goal here is the Car should feel that I have connected a wired phone and the phone should feel that it's connected to wireless Carplay/Android Auto.

I found [Certified Wireless USB](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_USB), but I don't think the phone will consider it for Carplay/Android.

Please guide me if there are existing solutions, would love to do a DIY.

My question may sound stupid, as I'm new to electronics.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [USB/IP](https://docs.kernel.org/usb/usbip_protocol.html) protocol. A small Linux computer, like a Raspberry Pi Zero, can act as a server that exposes its attached USB device (the car's infotainment system) via USB/IP on a Wifi network. Another system with a Linux kernel (such as an Android phone) can then connect to this server and drive the exposed USB device as if it was attached locally. For this to work, the `vhci-hcd` driver must be available in the phone's Linux kernel. You can enable it via the `CONFIG_USBIP_VHCI_HCD` kernel configuration or compile it as a loadable module (`vhcd-hci.ko`).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I want to avoid using a Rasberry Pi or any other computer as it will be similar to what exists in the market. I wonder if there is an IC that can act as a receiver to Carplay/Android Auto, then I can forward this signal to a USB protocol-related IC which can make it cheaper and lighter to build.

Comment: @RajRohitYadav There's this, using an ESP32: https://github.com/chegewara/esp32-usbip-poc It might not work as well as a Pi, though.

Comment: This is better, thanks again! I don't think there is a pre-baked IC that takes care of the automotive connection. Now, if I buy `ESP32` and connect my mobile to it via Bluetooth and wifi, I don't think the phone will consider `ESP32` as an automotive device, now making `ESP32` act as a car is a challenge.